# Combining control names

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is there a way to get a control by name by using a combined name (just like a messagebox: `MessageBox.Show("hi 1 " + lbltext.Text + " hi 2.");`)? For example I am using a label that has the name lblName, I want to use a tag of a button: button.Tag = "Name";

I tried simular things like this, but I could not get it to work:

```
lbl+"(string)button.Tag".Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
formName.Controls.Find("lbl" + button.Tag.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
((TextBox)Controls["tb1"]).Text = "hey";
```

the tb1 can be anything, i mean however you chose to compose it, but it should, of course, exist in the control collection.